# What is the equivalent of System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen in UWP?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I need to use `CopyFromScreen` but as far as I can see System.Drawing.Graphics is unavailable on the Universal Windows Platform. What can I use instead?

Comment: Are you trying to capture a screenshot of the desktop or just your app? ``System.Drawing.Graphics`` is based on GDI+ which is not supported for UWP. You should use XAML or Direct2D (via [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D)) or Direct3D (via [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or something equivalent).

Comment: I'm trying to screenshot the whole desktop

Comment: Um, UWP apps run on things that aren't desktops. What would it mean to take a screen shot on a HoloLens? Capturing data from other applications would also introduce security issues.

Comment: UWPs don't have access to the user's desktop as that would be an easy way to write spyware. You can make screen-shots of your own render targets, but not capture other people's stuff ala snip.

Comment: Alright so I hope they introduce some way to do it on the desktop. I know I can just make a classic program but of course going forward, things would be in UWP and it would suck to not have a an API to access it as all the other major operating systems have it. Otherwise, how would programs like Camtasia or screenshot tools work when UWP is the standard and classic programs are phased out.